# Private GitHub's repos + SSH + pip = headache

Tags: python, module, pip, package

I am new to Pyhton.
I am working with private GitHub's repos and `git+ssh://` schema along with `pip install` to keep things moduled and be able to maitain those independently.
However, it is an endless pain to make things "compile":

> There was an exception (ModuleNotFoundError) importing your module.

...this messages has became my best fried.

So assume I got a package dealing with main database:

```
> db (root folder)
> | -> setup.py (package metadata)
> | -> __init__.py (notifying the system that this is a module)
> | -> db1.py (codebase)
> | -> db2.py (another codebase)
```

and then I got another package, where I'd like to consume the `db`: after `pip install ...` I do something like `from db.db1 import SomeStuff` and then try to run it... though it does not work and I can't get why.

After all, my question is: how do I maintain separated packages such that those can be easily picked up by other packages without having to fight with the system all the time?
How do I debug errors and ask system for more meaningful messages than just `ModuleNotFoundError`? What tools can help me to fix it quickly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the root directory (the db directory) is in your *PYTHON PATH*. If you're using [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and pip, this db directory is always in that PYTHON PATH so you do not have to care about it.

So you can import, from anywhere:

```
from db.db1 import SomeStuff
```

And it should work.

It's a good practice to use virtual env to have environments that do not interfere with each other. You should try it.